# Lock a logo in Word 2016

Tags: lock

We have a new logo and people are asking for us to add the logo to their word documents. We want to lock the image only so that it can not be lifted or altered but that they can still make changes to their copy with in the document. I know how to do this in the header and footer by placing a continuous break and locking down that section. But how do I do that if the logo is in the middle of the layout?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to protect an image from copying, without severely
limiting the use of the document.
This is because there are many ways to avoid the protection,
like for example printing the document to PDF and lifting the image from there.

You may however lock an image against deletes and moves this way:

- Enable the developer tab : In menu File > Options > Customize Ribbon,
  in "Choose commands from" select "Main Tabs", check-mark "Developer"
  on the right, click OK.
- In Developer tab, click "Design Mode"
- Click where you want to insert the picture
- In the Controls section, click the "Picture Content Control" icon
- Click inside the control so a rectangle is selected
- You may now right-click the rectangle and paste an image, or insert it
  via the Insert tab
- In Developer tab, click Properties
- Check "Content control cannot be deleted" and "Contents cannot be edited"
- Click OK
- Click "Design Mode" again to terminate it.

[image]